# How to do a Room request inside of a class method?

Tags: android, android-room

I follower exactly this tutorial in order to implement Room in my Android project : 
https://www.techiediaries.com/android-room-tutorial/

I want  to have a method inside my class Traject that takes a List of TrajectJson and add it to the Database using my trajectDao. 
But the problem is i cant access the database in my class method because it needs a context.

Is there a way to get the instance of my database without a context?

Comment: Usually, you start from an Activity. If you create a class inside the activity, which needs a context, then create your class object with the context of the activity (Context to the constructor). If  I understand correctly, this wouldn't answer your question but may solve your problem.

Comment: Yes i see What you mean thanks you !